# How to execute task on all hosts from group when playbook is executed with limited hosts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-role

**Scenario**
I have a group `A` in my inventory, where `A` contains `a1,a2,a3` hosts. It does mean that I can write in my playbook `X.yml`:

```
- hosts: A
  roles:
    - role:
      name: r
```

The problem is about playbook `X` is started with limited number of hosts, namely launch of `ansible-playbook X` is limited to host `a1`.  This playbook `X` invoke role `r` (which is executed on host `a1`). I wouldn't like to change this behaviour (in other words I would like to preserve this limitation, don't ask why please).

**Question**
Is it possible to write task in role `r` in such way that it will be executed on all hosts from group `A` even if playbook is limited to host `a1`?   Please keep in mind that my inventory contains group `A`.

If not, could you suggest me another approach?
The one that I can do is:

```
- hosts: A
  tasks:
    - name: "This task"
```

Comment: With [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook) any combination of roles and hosts is possible.

Comment: If you are running ansible with `--limit`, I don't think you can get it to execute on any hosts that are not part of the current limit configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for certain, but this might work:

```
- name: Run task on hosts in group A
  some_random_module:
    var1: value1
    var2: value2
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ groups['A'] }}"
```

No promises.